# Cross browser and cross device testing: Why are some sites not viewable on iPad Peek?

Tags: cross-browser

I'm in the process of testing how my site looks on the iPad devices. I'm using the [iPad Peek](http://ipadpeek.com/) tool to view how it looks.

Why is it that some sites are viewable through iPad Peek (buddypress.org is an example) yet some sites are not viewable (wordpress.com being an example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPad Peek uses frames to display the content of other web pages, wordpress.com does not permit cross-origin framing whereas buddypress.org does.

Response header from wordpress.com:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

More information on the X-Frame-Options response header:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Thanks for the link and info. Why would WordPress choose to not permit cross-origin framing? i.e. what are the pros and cons associated with allowing cross-origin framing?

Comment: Many reasons, some technical, some not. One possible reason for sites to not allow this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking